# Save UV pass of specific object to file for later modification of texture

Tags: python, uv, render-passes

beginner here.
I want to save my rendered images together with auxiliary data that can later be used outside of blender. Specifically, I want to change the texture of a simple object (say, a cube or a cylinder) in the rendered images, inside a python script.
So I thought of saving something like the UV coordinates of that object in each rendered image.
I want to somehow capture the light interaction with that object, so that later on, modifying the texture would look real.
I thought of the "map uv" and "cryptomatte" nodes such in [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kBIVQbkWQI&ab_channel=TheInfinites), but not sure how to save the uv pass file and use it afterward outside of blender.

Also, is it possible to do that in Eevee as well? if so, any suggestion on how to better define the process so that lights still look good?

Your help is highly appreciated!

Many thanks,
Matan

Comment: Umm, exporting a 3D model in most formats will include its UV mapping. Exporting textures made in blender is simple, though sometimes the system may not know exactly what images to export, and will lean toward none at all. Why do you need something different..?

Comment: I want to produce a set of images with multiple views of an object and later on,  outside of blender, be able to project desired texture image on top of that object for each image.
I don't want to limit myself to simple planar object and use homographies for that purpose. Anyhow - it's reasonable that the render engine can do it, as it is part of its pipeline.

Comment: no, it’s not reasonable, since you’re asking blender to export basically a 3-D model as a 2-D image that can be re-interpreted into 3-D. Why not just export a regular 3-D model, like OBJ, and then put different textures on it and render at different angles in your other program?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To clarify, I want to render a bunch of views and then let external program to "play" with the object texture afterwards. The whole point is to avoid the slow renders afterward. My object is low poly and simple relative to the rest of the scene. The python program that will consume these images doesn't involve a renderer and should modify this object's texture thousands times..

Comment: “Rendering“ is simply taking information and turning it into something you can see, which is happening in that case. This can be done in milliseconds with OpenGL. I recommend the external program just use the same depth of field and such, and basically composite OpenGL render of your object over a Cycles render of the background with shadows from the object in place.

Comment: Thanks. But for the OpenGL render it also needs the knowledge of the lights and camera pose for each image, right?
I wanted to avoid that and approximate by something like giving the object in blender a constant albedo and later on, in the other program multiply the object mask by the required texture. Sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: UV Pass: https://youtu.be/aVfbEgMFbvA